# Why does this problem have one less root for x?

Tags: logarithms

Problem statement (Problem $6$):

[image]

This is my work below:

[image]
The answer of $x$ is $2$ and $8$. but my answer is $1$/ $\sqrt{3}$ and it is a credible answer if you solve it. Why is this happening?

Comment: https://ibb.co/doDLcc

Comment: Your work yielded the answer $x = 81$. Are you mixing up the problems?

Comment: Nope there are two answers -81 and 2

Comment: The $x=2$ corresponds to $x-1=1$ and $1^a=1^b$ for every $a, b$

Comment: Dude you did it so easily and I was like what the hell’s wrong with me since 2-3 days. Thanks though you could’ve written it as an answer you know...to get the upvote

Comment: It's a hassle to write answers from the phone and imo 10k is enough for me, anyway it's mostly experience, the more problems you do the easier it will be for you to spot things like this.

Answer (score 3):

There are two answers, $81$ and $2$.

If $a$ is positive, and $s,t$ are real, the equation
$$a^s = a^t$$
holds if and only if $a=1$ or $s=t$.

You analyzed the case $s=t$, which yields $x=81$.

You missed the case $a=1$, which yields $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

When $x=1/\sqrt3$, $x-1<0$ and so $(x-1)^7<0$.
But $|x-1|>0$ and so $|x-1|^{\textrm{nasty expression}}>0$.
Thus $1/\sqrt3$ cannot be a solution.

Comment: Yeah that’s resolved even if I put it in the nasty expression but how does x=2 come? I mean this question has repeated twice in the book and has 2 as an answer both times...

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you are looking for a solution under the condition $(x-1)>0$.

Note that since $t=\log_3 x$ the solutions are $x=81$ and $x=\frac1{\sqrt3}$.

As pointed out by [quasi](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2659862/505767), the other solution come from the trivial case $x-1=1$.

Comment: Yeah but how does value of x come to be 2? I get the x-1>0

Comment: That could be... the study material’s the nastiest then. This question was repeated further,in a multiple choice question. The three values we have -2,81,1/3^-1/2 were in the options and bam,2 was the answer again. Legend of Typos

Comment: A comment just answered that...

Comment: @DilinFinn Yes of course, we have also the case $x-1=1$ which leads to x=2.